# Remove individual theme option fields from Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm afraid I'm not too clued up with this sort of thing but you guys will hopefully be able to help out.

I'm working with a theme that has way too many options in the back end and most of them aren't needed. This theme is a Job Agency theme that we're using for a client's site and they will need the data entry for job inputting to be much simpler than it is.

Please can someone point me in the right direction for editing and/or removing theme options fields.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated.

This image shows the theme options I mean
[image]